# I can't get the title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('#campanya').change(function(){
        if($('#campanya').val() != 0){
            $('#tipoCampanya').val($('#campanya :selected').attr('title'));
            $('#idCampanya').val($('#campanya').val());
            $('#cargaempleados').submit();
        }     
});
```

I also tried with:

```
 $('#campanya').change(function(){
            if($('#campanya').val() != 0){
                $('#tipoCampanya').val(this.options[this.selectedIndex].title);
                $('#idCampanya').val($('#campanya').val());
                $('#cargaempleados').submit();
            }     
    });
```

But I have the same result ""

The select element looks like this:

```
<select id="campanya">
  <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
  <option title="tiendas" value="41">RENOVES OCT-NOV 2012</option>
  <option title="captación" value="43">ALEJANDRO CVT</option>
 </select>
```

I'm confused, I have the same application running in two different servers and in one works fine, how it was developed and in the another one doesn't work... , when the element it's loaded with its needed titles how shows the DOM). 
The only reason that I can think off is the char encoding. The value of the title attribute can contain special chars, as you can see.

But, all that happens is in a client side and in this part there is nothing changed(the same browser, the same jQuery lib..) the only thing is how the values come from MySQL. That's the only server side involved in this case.

Does anyone have any idea what's happening?

Comment: [this seems to work](http://jsbin.com/oqefub/1/edit). Are you sure you're not just losing the content of the page because of the submit ?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm inside $(function(){}), I'm testing with no submit , and don't have any error in console. And the DOM has the values I need, but it returns "", but I can see the values, in fact I get the value attribute. And more unusual... If I change with the title captación by captacion in only one, inmediately it returns the correct title.

Comment: jQuery version, browser?

Comment: If you suspect an encoding error, you should first check your html headers then look at the HTPP response headers. Of course I assume your file is correctly encoded.

Comment: Guys... seriously... stop answer that "it works", we know it and it doesn't help OP.

Comment: ha haa it seems big down voting war

Comment: It seems I don't explained me clearly.. I know how to retrieve the atributes of an html element with plain JS or jQuery it's easy task, that code it's running in one production server, but in another one that I'm testing that doesn't work with the same browser at the same time in different URLs

Comment: @jortsc that's why epascarello and me asked you questions regarding the context, encoding, headers.

Comment: @dystroy and epascarello thank you for your answer, this is the meta:  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> , the jQuery version is the same, the same browser. I think this is the way but something is failing. I'm confused :s

Comment: And is your document encoded in UTF8 ? No hidden char ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But I have to check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line inside the document `head` tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

If your page is HTML5, add following

```
<meta charset=ISO-8859-1 />
```

Comment: It's a good way, but I need to work with UTF-8, I'll try it and if it works I'll think about

Comment: if you want to use `UTF-8`, you have to use `UTF-8` characters.

Comment: Yes, but I'm doing it <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: `ó` is not an `UTF-8` character. so you have to set correct encoding or remove incorrect characters

Comment: I see, I have to change it to &#243;(is the utf code for that letter)?